# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file on line 59

Tags: php, html

i get the following error:

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file on line 59

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once("FormFunctions.php");
require_once("ValidationFunction.php");

$errors = array();
$message = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){ // form was submitted
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);

        // validations
        $fields_required = array("username", "password");
        foreach($fields_required as $field){
            $value = trim($_POST[$field]);
            if (!has_presence($value)){
            $errors[$field] =  ucfirst($field) . " cannot be blank";
            }
        }
        $field_max_length = array("username" => 10, "password" => 5);
        foreach($fields_max_length as $field => $max){
            $value = trim($_POST[$field]);
            if (!max_length($value, $max)){
            $errors[$field] =  ucfirst($field) . " is too long";

        if (empty($errors)){
            // try to log in
            if ($username == "CIS108" && $password == "PHP"){ // login successful
                redirect_to("process1.php");
            } else{ // login failed
                $message = "Login failed! Username and password combination was incorrect.<br/>Please log in again.";
            }
        }

} else{
$message = "please log in.";
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"               "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Form Two</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Third form login</h1>
<b><?php echo $message;?></b>
<b><?php echo form_errors($errors);?></b>
<form action="Form3.php" method="post">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" /><br />
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" value="" /><br />
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error. I have sifted through this code over and over but can't seem to see what is wrong. I am pretty new at writing code, so it would surprise me if its something simple, but i just don't see it.

Comment: Which one is line 59?

Comment: I see too many questions like this. Take the time to learn how to [interpret errors and fix your code](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/05/fixing-php-errors/).

Comment: I believe its </html>

Comment: Jason McCreary, thank you for your input. I think i had a few if statement closing brackets missing